# Adding values linked to dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a regular date range of let's say, one month. Then I have another dataframe with a few dates of that same month and a value for those dates. I'd like to pass those values to the first dataframe same dates:

```
Dataframe with consecutive dates
0 2016-11-01
1 2016-11-02
2 2016-11-03
3 2016-11-04
4 2016-11-05
5 2016-11-06
…

Dataframe with just some dates and values
0 2016-11-02 55
1 2016-11-04 34
2 2016-11-06 21
…

Dataframe I am trying to get
0 2016-11-01
1 2016-11-02 55
2 2016-11-03
3 2016-11-04 34
4 2016-11-05
5 2016-11-06 21
…
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make an attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), `on` can be omited if there are no other same column names in both `DataFrames` as joining columns (if not use `on='date'`):

```
print (df1)
         date
0  2016-11-01
1  2016-11-02
2  2016-11-03
3  2016-11-04
4  2016-11-05
5  2016-11-06

print (df2)
         date  val
0  2016-11-02   55
1  2016-11-04   34
2  2016-11-06   21

df1['val'] = df1.date.map(df2.set_index('date')['val'])
print (df1)
         date   val
0  2016-11-01   NaN
1  2016-11-02  55.0
2  2016-11-03   NaN
3  2016-11-04  34.0
4  2016-11-05   NaN
5  2016-11-06  21.0
```

---

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
print (df)
         date   val
0  2016-11-01   NaN
1  2016-11-02  55.0
2  2016-11-03   NaN
3  2016-11-04  34.0
4  2016-11-05   NaN
5  2016-11-06  21.0
```

Comment: bah you beat me on this :) so deleted... also `df1.merge(df2, how="left", on="date")` with the `on` just in case there are more cols in df1, df2.

Comment: Thank you, I add it to answer.